# Designing a Work Scheduling Database with Multiple Variables?

Tags: php, mysql, database-schema

I'm trying to design a database schema for a schedule application that I am working on.  I have a way of doing it, but it seems a little clunky.  I'm curious if this is the nature of the beast because of the variable involved.

The application is similar to a job board, but with a scheduling component.  You can create a job (or "project"), and then set work dates, and say which positions are open for the job.  Other can sign up for the job and either be hired or denied.

The problems:

-The job doesn't run concurrent dates, so there could be 10 work days spread over two months.

-The positions change from job to job.  They're picked from a list, but one job may have 10 unique open positions, while another may have 5.

My idea, which definitely feels clunky is to have "openPositions" as one table with [jobId, positionName, date] and a second table with "jobApply" with [jobId, positionName, date, acceptFlag].  So each date has an entry for each position.  Obviously this gets exponentially large (openPositions would have [#days * #positions] rows).  I could cut down on this by forcing people who sign up for a position to be available on every day, but I wanted to allow for flexibility in scheduling.

This project as a whole is bigger than the stuff I have been working, but I'm excited to tackle it.  I'd love to hear any ideas, please let me know if clarifications are necessary.

**Edit:** Quick less-abstract example:

**Project 1**

**Dates of project:** 3/1, 3/5, 3/6, 3/9, 4/2, 4/5, 4/8

**Positions needed:** Project Lead, Programmer 1, Programmer 2, Modeler, Level Designer, Intern

So my (clunky) version would have entries into openPositions as:

(3/1, Project Lead), (3/5, Project Lead), (3/6, Project Lead), (3/1, Programmer 1) and on, and on.

Again, obviously this has a lot of entries, which is my concern (in this case 7 dates x 6 positions, so 42 rows in the database).  Hope this helps a bit.

Comment: Can you make the scenario a little less abstract - sometimes I find that helps to structure the problem.

Comment: Added some clarification.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't very clear to me, but do you know the list of positions required for the job when you start the job and will the positions be the same on EVERY SINGLE work day?

if so, make a table "positions_required" with two columns in it (jobID, position) and enter there the job_id and the positions required.

That way you will enter the dates of work for each project into your other table.

You will have 3 tables but only 1 + m + n records (relation 1:m (jobs:positions) and 1:n (jobs:dates) ) ) instead of 1+m*n (as in your scenario)